# Warning: array_search() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given in

Tags: php, arrays

Here is part of my code:

```
$csv        = file_get_contents('states.csv');
$csv        = mb_convert_encoding($csv, 'UTF-8');
$json       = csvToJson($csv);
$json_state = json_decode($json, true);
$bilProvin  = trim($order['billing_address']['province']);
$bilCountry = trim($order['billing_address']['country']);
foreach ($json_state as $keys) {
    if (array_search($bilProvin,$bilCountry, $keys)) // Added trim 
        {
        $bilState = substr($keys['var1'], 3);
        if ($bilState != 'KY') {
            $order['billing_address']['province'] = $bilState;
        } else {
            $order['billing_address']['province'] = "";
        }
    }
 }
```

How to search `$bilCountry` in array? from my above code shows Warning: array_search() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given in `C:\xampp\htdocs\cats\index-oauth.php on line 162` as lots of lines.

Can anyone help me?

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: What do you want us to say? The error message is clear enough: you've provided a string when you should have provided an array.

Comment: read the manual of the [array_search](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.array-search.php) first.

Comment: `$bilCountry` is a string, not an array. You also have 3 parameters, but `array_search()` only takes 2 (`needle`, `haystack`) with the 3rd (`strict`) is `bool`->`true|false`. [`array_search ( mixed $needle , array $haystack [, bool $strict = false ] )`](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.array-search.php)

Comment: How to serch $bilCountry?

Comment: I m new to php, can anyone tell me how to edit my code to search $bilCountry? Thank you..

Comment: Can you post what `var_dump($bilCountry)` looks like. Is it an array?

Answer (score 1):

Trim() returns a string. Parameter 2 is expecting an array. Maybe you can describe what you are trying to do, but if you are trying to look through a list of items put your data into an array.

Comment: can you help me with my code, how to seach $bilCountry?

Comment: @user3756273 It's not clear what you are trying to accomplish but if youuunderstand your data tgat will help you greatly. Make use of print_r() to see structures like $json_state or $keys. It looks like you might need to array_search on $bilCountry and $bilProvin separately against $keys with an || (or) to see if either match the condition.